# Add something between every element already in list - OCaml

Tags: list, ocaml

I'm wondering if there's a list function that allows you to add a separator between every element in a list.

For example:

```
[1;2;3;4;5] -> [1;0;2;0;3;0;4;0;5]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean a function in the OCaml standard library, there is none like this. You can find this information yourself in the [OCaml manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/). The list functions are described [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html).

The [Core list module](https://blogs.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/110.01.00/doc/core/#Core_list) has `Core_list.intersperse`, which does exactly what you describe.

The [Batteries list module](http://ocaml-batteries-team.github.io/batteries-included/hdoc2/BatList.html) has `BatList.interleave`, which also does exactly what you describe (plus a little more).

Comment: i'm a newbie at OCaml -- how do I install the Core List module?

Comment: It's not hard, but you might want to start further back in the chain. Look at http://OCaml.org. They have good instructions for getting started with OCaml. (FWIW the interleave function is trivial to write. But knowing about OCaml libraries is good.)

Answer (score 1):

You could define a function like this:

```ml
let rec intersperse sep ls =
    match ls with
    | [] | [_] -> ls
    | hd::tl -> hd :: sep :: intersperse sep tl
```

Example usage:

```
intersperse 0 [1; 2; 3; 4; 5]
(* Returns: [1; 0; 2; 0; 3; 0; 4; 0; 5] *)
```